# Cannot add "User" data model to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm following Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Harlt. My data model is named `User`. When I try to add `User` in console, it generates the following error.
    ArgumentError: Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both)

Console code:

```
User.create!( :name => "Hussain" , :email => "Hussain@example.com" )
```

User model code:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :name,  :presence => true, 
                      :length => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true,
                      :format => { :key => email_regex },
                      :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

end
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: How are you adding the users? Please post the code.

Comment: Do you have any validations in user.rb? If so Please post it.

Comment: Please post the User model code.

Comment: Try changing this `validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :key => email_regex }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }` to `validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :with=> email_regex }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }`

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks !

Comment: @Pavan you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @vjdhama Yeah! Just posted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this

```
validates :email, :presence => true, 
                  :format => { :key => email_regex }, 
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

to

```
validates :email, :presence => true, 
                  :format => { :with=> email_regex }, 
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```